# Java class error android

Tags: java, android, apk

```
03-13 15:27:57.592: I/Process(1985): Sending signal. PID: 1985 SIG: 9
03-13 15:27:58.558: D/AndroidRuntime(2062): Shutting down VM
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): Process: com.example.cabbookinghome, PID: 2062
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at com.example.cabbookinghome.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:38)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.cabbookinghome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     ... 17 more
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):         ... 18 more
03-13 15:27:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

can someone here tell me whats wrong or why i'm getting no class error?

Comment: This is not meaningfully a duplicate of a generic Java question.  It is very much a duplicate, but needs to be pointed at one which is specific to this type of Android issue, particularly with how a class can be present at compile time but missing at runtime - an extremely common issue with the particular package that is missing in this case.

Comment: There is a chance that you did not setup support v7 properly

Comment: it would be nice if you had posted a `build.gradle`˙file that contains the dependency for `v7 support library`

Comment: Happened to me sometimes, don't know the reason, compile it again and try

Answer (score 0):

The only meaningful line here is:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
```

which means that the compiler cannot find the Android's appcompat library.
Check if your build.gradle contains the following line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
```

Comment: Avoid using the + sign. I recommend you stick to a fixed version.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This helps to avoid sudden compilation failures when library changes in a way that breaks backward compatibility.